# Can not autowire bean in junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

This is my simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:root-context.xml")
public class ServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    private CafeService cafeDataService;


    @Test
    public void testCafeService()
    {
        assertTrue(cafeDataService.get()!=null);
    }
}
```

My root-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.tenet.cafe" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:array>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:array>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>


<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="ru.tenet.cafe.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>


<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<beans:bean id="dataSourceMain" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.101.158:5432/cafe" />
    <beans:property name="user" value="postgres" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="123" />
    <beans:property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="8" />
    <beans:property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <beans:property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
    <beans:property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <beans:property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMain" />
    <beans:property name="configLocation">
        <beans:value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>

</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

This is what I've got:

> Error creating bean with name 'ru.tenet.cafe.ServiceTest': Injection
>   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private ru.tenet.cafe.service.CafeService
>   ru.tenet.cafe.ServiceTest.cafeDataService; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [ru.tenet.cafe.service.CafeService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

What is wrong? I can autowire my service inside controller, but my test doesn't let me do that.

Comment: the first thing that comes to mind is that your `root-context.xml` is not configured properly .

Comment: Is CafeService annotated with @Service/@Component?

Comment: No. CafeServiceImpl is annotated